# Download from http server all directories,files and subdirectories and so on

Tags: linux, download, http, directory-listing

I want to download from remote http server all files directories,files and so on. I found some solutions to ftp server,but doesn't work to http. Until now no luck with wget -r or -m. It download all direcotories in the root and the respective index.html. Not all files and sub-directory under such it(note the sub-directory may have another directory and so on)

not sure on tags fix for me if needs. Note: I'm not a native english speaker,sorry for bad english.

Comment: Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with arbitrary files in it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it

Comment: or you might not have access to the file/dirs

Comment: Until at moment is working fine. I'm downloading the directories and its contents. I'd love to suggest to you: port this comment to answer and I give +1 and mark as accept if such options to wget will do what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!

Comment: you can just upvote my comment if you want, and give the guy in the link an upvote too ...thanks though

Comment: @Logman: Done! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web servers don't give you a directory listing. (Not unless you tell them to do so.) SO, in the general case, this is impossible.

You can probably use rsync+ssh for this. Or FTP.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. `wget` application is doing the job with `-r --no-parent --reject "index.html*"` flags,as was suggested by the Jeremy Ruten's answer in the stackoverflow linked by Logman. I forget to mention,it's a http server,but do the files directories listing exactly as a FTP server.